# I'm setting up a hotel database and can't seem to figure out how to eliminate already reserved rooms

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My hotel database has five tables and a web interface that can be used for booking. 
The web interface is able to eliminate available rooms based on price, number of guests and location of hotel. I can't, however, figure out how I would go about eliminating rooms based on dates it is already reserved on.

The database looks like this

**TABLE roomtypes**

```
ID - int
Type - varchar
Price - int
maxGuests - int
```

**TABLE guests**

```
ID - int
name - varchar
email - varchar
simi - varchar
```

**TABLE locations**

```
ID - int
name - varchar
```

**TABLE rooms**

```
ID - int
typeID - int(refernces type.ID)
hotelID - int(references locations.ID)
```

**TABLE bookings**

```
ID - int
guestID - int(references guests.ID)
hotelID - int(references locations.ID)
roomID - int(references rooms.ID)
arrivalDate - date
leavingDate - date
```

So, the SQL query I use to eliminate rooms looks like this:

```
SELECT rooms.ID, type.type, type.price 
FROM rooms 
INNER JOIN type ON rooms.typeID = type.ID 
WHERE rooms.hotelID = $hotelLocation 
AND room.typeID = $roomType 
AND type.maxGuests >= $numberOfGuests
```

I've been thinking that I might need to use subqueries to select dates from the bookings table and compare those to dates that the user inputs via the web interface. But I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: You'll hafta `JOIN` on `bookings` in order to pull booking data, then presumably check to see if there's a current reservation in that room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rooms.ID, type.type, type.price 
FROM rooms 
INNER JOIN type ON rooms.typeID = type.ID 
WHERE rooms.hotelID = $hotelLocation 
AND room.typeID = $roomType 
AND type.maxGuests >= $numberOfGuests
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE  bookings.roomID = rooms.roomID
    -- Depending on the interpretation of arrivalDate and
    -- leavingDate, the comparators may need to be <= and >=
    AND    bookings.arrivalDate < $requestedLeavingDate
    AND    bookings.leavingDate > $requestedArrivalDate
)
```

Comment: Any reason to avoid 2nd JOIN?

Comment: it might be because the booking information isn't important other than ensuring that spot isn't filled, so no need to join it on. It's about the same. performance-wise, perhaps even a little faster?